# Alter mysql result to product table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
SELECT t.typeName, m.quantity, m.typeID
FROM invTypeMaterials AS m
LEFT JOIN invTypes AS t
ON m.materialTypeID = t.typeID
WHERE m.typeID = 222'
```

it produces this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [typeName] => Tritanium [quantity] => 204 [typeID] => 222 ) [1] => Array ( [typeName] => Pyerite [quantity] => 17 [typeID] => 222 ) [2] => Array ( [typeName] => Nocxium [quantity] => 1 [typeID] => 222 ) )
```

How in sweet good god do I turn it into this.

```
Tritanium   Pyerite     Nocxium 
204          17          1
```

This should be really simple and I'm sure it is, but no matter what I try I can't get it to show up like that.

Tried this and so much else:

```
 $i=0;
// output data of each row
   foreach ($users as $user) {

    //echo count($user['typeID']);
    echo '<td>' . $user["quantity"] . '</td>';
    //echo '<td>' . $user["typeID"] . '</td>';
    $i++ ;


 if($i % 8 == 0){
   echo '<td></td>';

}

elseif($i % 1 == 0) {
    echo '</tr>';
}

    if($i<5) { echo '<td></td>';    

}
```

For chosen answer

```
Tritanium   Pyerite Mexallon    Tritanium   Pyerite Mexallon    Isogen  Tritanium   Mexallon    Isogen
107 213 107 56000   12050   2100    450 134 267 134
```

Comment: what code before this? . This is the code

Comment: hey @Drew it's also possible which you are saying is not possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//execute query
//fetch data into an array like Array(Array(name, quantity, id), Array(name, quantity, id)...)
//Loop through the array:
echo '<table>';
foreach ($results as $val) {
     echo '<tr><td>'.$val["typeName"].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$val["quantity"].'</td>':
     echo '<td>'.$val["typeID"].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Also `i%1 == 0`? Really? :D

**EDIT:**
Aaah, I get the problem now. You want the list to be horizontally, not vertically. Well that is a little more tricky and the only solution that I could think of is using three loops:

```
//same as above to load the array
echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($results as $val)
      echo '<td>'.$val["typeName"].'</td>';
  echo '</tr><tr>';
    foreach ($results as $val)
      echo '<td>'.$val["quantity"].'</td>';
  echo '</tr><tr>';
    foreach ($results as $val)
      echo '<td>'.$val["typeID"].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: This is very close.

It produces this:

Tritanium 204 222
Pyerite 17 222
Nocxium 1 222

Comment: See my edit. It's not a nice looking solution, but it's the only way since HTML tables are designed row by row and not column by column

Comment: Editing this a bit helped me achieve my result. thank you. I used the same three loops to get it. Ugly but it works :)

Comment: This breaks when i select a bunch of them

Comment: What do you mean by "a bunch" of them? Do you mean more columns or more rows?

Comment: sorry, if i take out the WHERE clause, so a bunch of rows

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or something of "how" it breaks? Because actually that solution should support "endless" rows (but not endless columns)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96721/discussion-between-keaner-and-tobias-baumeister).

Answer (score 0):

Surely this will help you

```
<?php
$key = array();
$values = array();
foreach ($users as $user => $value) {
    $key[] = $user;
    $values[] = $value;
}
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($key as $single) {
    echo '<td>' . $single . '</td>';
}
echo "<tr>";

echo "<tr>";
foreach ($values as $single) {
    echo '<td>' . $single . '</td>';
}
echo "<tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: This will help you iff there is one record as in your situation.

Answer (score -1):

if you want one header and others as its value just like below, then try this

```
Tritanium   Pyerite     Nocxium 
204          17          1 
205          24          3
```

=============================

```
<?php
$keys = array_keys($users[0]);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($keys as $single) {
    echo '<th>' . $single . '</th>';
}
echo "<tr>";

echo "<tr>";
foreach ($users as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<td>' . $value. '</td>';
}
echo "<tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
```